# Rails5.0.0.1からRails5.2にアップグレードしたらPumaが立ち上がらない。

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Qiitaなどで一通り確認した上でご質問します。
5.0.0.1から5.2を導入時に、bootsnapを入れました。それによって、以下の状況が起きており、bootsnapを外すとbootsnapが無いと表示されます。

bootsnapのキャッシュもクリアしましたが無理でした。
お知恵をおかしください。

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.2.2 application starting in development 
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Exiting
Traceback (most recent call last):
    51: from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
    50: from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    49: from /Users/hogetaro/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    48: from /Users/hogetaro/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
    47: from /Users/hogetaro/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/command/base.rb:65:in `perform'
    46: from /Users/hogetaro/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
    45: from /Users/hogetaro/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
    44: from /Users/hogetaro/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    43: from /Users/hogetaro/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `perform'
    42: from /Users/hogetaro/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `tap'
    41: from /Users/hogetaro/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:147:in `block in perform'
    40: from /Users/hogetaro/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:51:in `start'
    39: from /Users/hogetaro/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:89:in `log_to_stdout'
    38: from /Users/hogetaro/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/server.rb:354:in `wrapped_app'
    37: from /Users/hogetaro/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:27:in `app'
    36: from /Users/hogetaro/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/server.rb:219:in `app'
    35: from /Users/hogetaro/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/server.rb:319:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    34: from /Users/hogetaro/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    33: from /Users/hogetaro/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
    32: from /Users/hogetaro/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
    31: from config.ru:in `<main>'
    30: from config.ru:in `new'
    29: from /Users/hogetaro/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
    28: from /Users/hogetaro/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
    27: from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    26: from config.ru:3:in `require_relative'
    25: from /Users/hogetaro/Documents/GitHub/fictapg/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    24: from /Users/hogetaro/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/application.rb:361:in `initialize!'
    23: from /Users/hogetaro/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
    22: from /Users/hogetaro/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    21: from /Users/hogetaro/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
    20: from /Users/hogetaro/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    19: from /Users/hogetaro/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
    18: from /Users/hogetaro/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
    17: from /Users/hogetaro/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    16: from /Users/hogetaro/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    15: from /Users/hogetaro/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    14: from /Users/hogetaro/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
    13: from /Users/hogetaro/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
    12: from /Users/hogetaro/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
    11: from /Users/hogetaro/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
    10: from /Users/hogetaro/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/devise-4.5.0/lib/devise/rails.rb:37:in `block in <class:Engine>'
     9: from /Users/hogetaro/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/devise-4.5.0/lib/devise/secret_key_finder.rb:12:in `find'
     8: from /Users/hogetaro/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/application.rb:399:in `secrets'
     7: from /Users/hogetaro/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/secrets.rb:26:in `parse'
     6: from /Users/hogetaro/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/secrets.rb:26:in `each_with_object'
     5: from /Users/hogetaro/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/secrets.rb:26:in `each'
     4: from /Users/hogetaro/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/secrets.rb:29:in `block in parse'
     3: from /Users/hogetaro/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/erb.rb:876:in `result'
     2: from /Users/hogetaro/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/erb.rb:876:in `eval'
     1: from (erb):22:in `<main>'
(erb):22:in `[]': no implicit conversion of Symbol into String (TypeError)
```

Comment: エラーメッセージによりますと、`tsort_each`あたりで`文字列への変換がされていません`というようなことを言っていると思いますが、値がちゃんと意図した型になっていますか？

Comment: ご回答いただきありがとうございます。すみませんが、これってどこのファイルのなんの文字列を指しているのかがわからなかったんですが、それはどのように探せばよいのでしょうか？Modelが膨大にあるため、絞り込みが難しいなと思いまして・・・

Comment: `t_sort.rb`というファイルの205行目あたりに`tsort_each`というファンクションかリストか何かがあるということだと思うのですが、そのあたりのコードを載せて頂けるともう少し分かるかもしれません。

Comment: t_sort.rb自体はruby本体のファイルだと思うので私が作ったものではないのですが・・・